# Canvas drawImage using data URL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'll start with the script:

```
  function saveInstance() {
   _savedInstance = document.getElementById('canvasID').toDataURL();
  }
  function restoreInstance() {
   ctx.drawImage(_savedInstance,0,0);
  }
```

The purpose is to save an instance of the canvas and re-apply it later [Similar to how ctx.save() saves the style and transformations].

However, I got the error that says incompatible types (Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17). Is there any canvas method that will allow me to use the data URL string to re-draw the instance?

**If there's a better way to implement this save/restore idea I have, that'd also be much appreciated.

-Firstmate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can create an image element with its source as `_savedInstance` and then draw it to the canvas.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = _savedInstance;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

Comment: Yes, you can also draw from a canvas/video element as well, see the spec here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage

Comment: Worked like a charm!
And thanks for the link Peol, that comes in handy for another part of the project XD

Comment: See also this issue in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57941

Comment: @Vanuan, how do you overcome the issue with the image not loading immediately if your method to load the image need to be blocking?