# Update canvas element on form submit - Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to update an HTML canvas element on form submission with Django.

I have my **views.py** that renders the **index.html** page with the processed data in JSON.

`return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'data': mark_safe(json.dumps(data))})`

This render method is inside of an `if request.method == 'POST'`, so essentially what's happening is it's sending the data through context to the HTML and JavaScript appropriately, however, I need canvas updates when I use the "submit" button.

`$('#form').submit(function() { /* all of my canvas logic */ });` Momentarily, the canvas will show the sign before the Django page is refreshed, and then reset to a blank canvas.

Presumably this is because nothing in views.py explicitly tells the index.html to have a new canvas on the page with data, but I can't seem to find any information or docs on this. Furthermore:

- Python tkinter or other GUI libraries don't really apply here.
- I can only change and update the canvas through JavaScript.
- I can't pass a whole HTML canvas element as context through the view.
- `e.preventDefault();` would cancel the whole submission; so if an input in the form changes, the POSTed data will not update, and in result, the drawn shapes on the canvas will not change.

Maybe there's a way to draw this *after* the form data is processed?

**TLDR**: How do I render a canvas based off of form data, and then have the canvas persist (or update) on the page after form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring out that I thought of how this data is being submitted completely wrong, and for my project specifically, there was a different solution that utilizes Django much better: actually using context. Oops!

But, for future reference on this issue in specific, there still may be solutions:

- [Canvas.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
- [Submit Canvas Data in HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048093/submit-canvas-data-in-an-html-form)
- [Send canvas image data in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711912/send-canvas-image-data-via-html-form-and-load-data-into-new-blank-canvas-page)